# undefined local variable or method `sub_task'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated project model that has one to one relation with and stage model that has one to many relation with task and task model that has one to many relation with sub_task. I have rendered nested table in project#show. now i am not able pass correct path to add sub_task button and edit task and sub_task button on project#show. add to sub task , edit and destroy is not working. What changes I need to do?

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: :sub_tasks}}).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks do
        resources :sub_tasks
      end
    end
  end
```

on project#show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to "Add Sub Task", new_project_stage_task_sub_task_url(@project, stage, sub_task), :class=>"button primary small" %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_stage_task_sub_task_path(task) %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sub_task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to "Add Sub Task", new_project_stage_task_sub_task_url(@project, stage, task)%></td>
```